# Adding labels to a bar chart with multiple data sets

Tags: labeling, charts

I am trying to plot multiple data sets on a bar chart with unrelated column labels for each data set...

Suppose my data is a list comprised of three different sub-lists of varying size, i.e., they have the form

```
{<Data Set 1 (2 Items)>, <Data Set 2 (4 Items)>, <Data Set 3 (8 Items)>}
```

I want to present the data in a bar chart, where I label each of the sub-lists its own label: Data Set 1 should be labeled `{0, 1}`, Data Set 2 should be labeled `{00, 01, 10, 11}` and Data Set 3 should be labeled `{000, 001, 010, ..., 111}`

How can I accomplish this?

In my current situation, I would like to add the binary expansion listed above to the following bar chart. The last bit of code is obviously wrong, but that's the problem I'm trying to fix.

```
BarChart[
  {{.45, .55}, 
   {0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.22}, 
   {0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0}},
  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
  ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
  ChartLabels -> 
    {{"Order 1", "Order 2", "Order 3"}, 
     {"0", "1", "00", "01", "10", "11", "000", "001", 
      "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"}}]
```

I[image]

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = {{.45, .55}, {0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.22}, {0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.25,  0.25, 0, 0.25, 0}}; 
collabels = {{"0", "1"}, {"00", "01", "10", "11"}, 
    {"000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"}};

labeleddata = MapThread[Labeled, #] & /@ Transpose[{data, collabels}] (*thanks: @eldo*)

BarChart[labeleddata, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Order 1", "Order 2", "Order 3"}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively,

```
rowlabels = {"Order 1", "Order 2", "Order 3"};

BarChart[Labeled @@@ Transpose[{labeleddata, rowlabels}], 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @EngineeringSquirrel, my pleasure, Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: A little bit clearer maybe: `MapThread[Labeled, #] & /@ Transpose...` - Something very nice and new to me

Comment: @eldo, thank you. Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Horrible and kludgy in comparison to @kglr's answer, but may provide a workaround in similar situations. `Epilog` can often be used to crowbar things in at the last minute:

```
data = {.45, .55, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.22, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0};
barlabels = {"0", "1", "00", "01", "10", "11", "000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"};
epilogtext = Text[#[[1]], Scaled[#[[2]]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{{"Order 1", "Order 2", "Order 3"}, {{0.1, -0.1}, {0.3, -0.1}, {0.7, -0.1}}}];
BarChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
ChartLabels -> barlabels, Epilog -> epilogtext, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[0.025], Automatic}}]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Also a useful answer! I appreciate the additional help!